# <*> of the instance <gen[1].*> is unconnected or connected to loadless signal

Tags: arrays, vhdl

when I'm synthesizing the following VHDL code I get the above error(s).

This is a toplevel design to connect multiple entities.

The component declaration:

```
    COMPONENT channel_memory IS
    PORT (
        clka : IN STD_LOGIC;
        rsta : IN STD_LOGIC;
        wea : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(0 DOWNTO 0):= (OTHERS => '0');
        addra : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(11 DOWNTO 0):=  (OTHERS => '0');
        dina : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 DOWNTO 0):=   (OTHERS => '0');
        douta : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 DOWNTO 0):= (OTHERS => '0')
        );
END COMPONENT;
COMPONENT MAX5190 IS
    PORT (  
        GCLK                            :   IN  STD_LOGIC;                      -- CLK in 200 MHz
        RSTN                            :   IN  STD_LOGIC;                      -- Reset
        OUTPUT_TRIGGER                  :   IN  STD_LOGIC;                      -- Enable the module    (from controller)
        TRIGGER_CHIRP                   :   IN  STD_LOGIC;                      -- Start chirping       (from channel delay)
        LOAD_ACK                        :   IN  STD_LOGIC;                      -- Data ready               
        DATA_LENGTH                     :   IN  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (11 DOWNTO 0); -- Total words to send to DAC
        DIN                             :   IN  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 DOWNTO 0) :=   (OTHERS => '0');    -- Actual data to send to DAC
        CHIRP_EN_TRIGGER                :   IN  STD_LOGIC;                      -- Enable dac >> ××××××××××××
                                                                    --                          ×
        -- Memory block                                                                         ×
        LOAD_OUTPUT                     :   OUT STD_LOGIC;                      -- Request data             ×
        DATA_ADDR                       :   OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (11 DOWNTO 0); -- Adress to read from      ×
                                                                    --                          ×
        CHIRP_EN                        :   OUT STD_LOGIC;                      -- opamp enable << ××××××××××
         -- MAX5190 outputs
        DAC_EN                          :   OUT STD_LOGIC;                      -- DAC Enable (always high)
        DAC_CS                          :   OUT STD_LOGIC;                      -- DAC chip select
        DAC_CLK                         :   OUT STD_LOGIC;                      -- DAC clock out
        DAC_DATA                        :   OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 DOWNTO 0)       :=  (OTHERS => '0') -- dac data
);
END COMPONENT;

COMPONENT memory_controll IS
    PORT(
        CLK                             : IN  STD_LOGIC;

        -- from controller
        DATA_IN                         : IN  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 15 DOWNTO 0 ); -- data to store
        DATA_LENGTH                     : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 11 DOWNTO 0 ); -- number of words to store
        RESET                           : IN  STD_LOGIC;                        -- reset module
        NEW_DATA                        : IN  STD_LOGIC;                        -- new data available flag
        WRITE_ENABLE                    : IN  STD_LOGIC;                        -- enable writing

        -- from MAX5190
        ADDRESS_SELECT                  : IN  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 11 DOWNTO 0 ) := (others => '0');  -- addres selected by MAX5190 driver
        REQUEST_DATA                    : IN  STD_LOGIC;                        -- request data
        DATA_OUT                        : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 15 DOWNTO 0 ); -- data to MAX5190 driver
        DATA_READY                      : OUT STD_LOGIC;                        -- data to MAX5190 driver ready

        -- to memory
        DOUTA                           : IN  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 15 DOWNTO 0 ) := (others => '0'); -- data from memory
        DINA                            : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 15 DOWNTO 0 ); -- data to memory
        ADDRA                           : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR ( 11 DOWNTO 0 ); -- addres to write or read
        WEA                             : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (  0 DOWNTO 0);  -- write enable
        RSTA                            : OUT STD_LOGIC                         -- reset memory

        );
```

The port mapping:

```
gen: for i in 1 to number_of_channels generate
    -- memory controll
memcont: memory_controll
    PORT MAP(
        CLK                             => clk400MHz,

        -- from controller
        DATA_IN                         => MEMORY_CONTROL_DATA,
        DATA_LENGTH                     => MEMORY_CONTROL_DATA_LENGTH,
        RESET                           => BUTTON,
        NEW_DATA                        => MEMORY_CONTROL_NEW_DATA,
        WRITE_ENABLE                    => MEMORY_CONTROL_WRITE_ENABLE,

        -- from MAX5190
        ADDRESS_SELECT                  => ADDRESS_SELECT   (i),
        REQUEST_DATA                    => REQUEST_DATA     (i),
        DATA_OUT                        => DATA_OUT         (i),
        DATA_READY                      => DATA_READY       (i),

        -- to memory
        DOUTA                           => DOUTA    (i),
        DINA                            => DINA     (i),
        ADDRA                           => ADDRA    (i),
        WEA                             => WEA      (i),
        RSTA                            => RSTA     (i)
        );

    -- max5190
max: max5190
    PORT MAP(
        GCLK                            => clk200MHz,
        RSTN                            => MAX5190_RESET,
        OUTPUT_TRIGGER                  => MAX5190_ENABLE,
        TRIGGER_CHIRP                   => TRIGGER_CHIRP            (i),
        LOAD_ACK                        => DATA_READY               (i),
        DATA_LENGTH                     => MAX5190_DATA_LENGTH,
        DIN                             => DATA_OUT                 (i),
        CHIRP_EN_TRIGGER                => MAX5190_CHIRP_ENABLE,

        -- Memory block         
        LOAD_OUTPUT                     => REQUEST_DATA     (i),
        DATA_ADDR                       => ADDRESS_SELECT   (i),

        CHIRP_EN                        => CHIRP_EN     (i),
         -- MAX5190 outputs
        DAC_EN                          => DAC_EN       (i),
        DAC_CS                          => DAC_CS       (i),
        DAC_CLK                         => CHANNEL_CLKS (i),
        DAC_DATA                        => CHANNELS     (i)
        );
    -- memory
mem: channel_memory
    PORT MAP(
        clka                            => clk400MHz,
        rsta                            => BUTTON,
        wea                             => WEA      (i),
        addra                           => ADDRA    (i),
        dina                            => DINA     (i),
        douta                           => DOUTA    (i)
        );
```

the package where I declared my types:

```
PACKAGE jelle IS
FUNCTION lookup (input: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 DOWNTO 0)) RETURN INTEGER;
FUNCTION jOR    (input: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR( 7 DOWNTO 0)) RETURN STD_LOGIC;
TYPE VECTOR_ARRAY   is array (POSITIVE) of STD_LOGIC_VECTOR( 7 downto 0);
TYPE ADDRESS_ARRAY  is array (POSITIVE) of STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(11 downto 0);
TYPE DATA_ARRAY     is array (POSITIVE) of STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0);
TYPE WEA_ARRAY      is array (POSITIVE) of STD_LOGIC_VECTOR( 0 downto 0);
```

END PACKAGE;

The previous time I synthesized the code these where warning, now they've changed to errors, but I think they're still pretty important.

```
INFO:Xst:3210 - "E:\Projects\VHDL\New_Phase\toplevel.vhd" line 288: Output port <CLK_OUT3> of the instance <dcm> is unconnected or connected to loadless signal.
INFO:Xst:3210 - "E:\Projects\VHDL\New_Phase\toplevel.vhd" line 288: Output port <LOCKED> of the instance <dcm> is unconnected or connected to loadless signal.

INFO:Xst:3210 - "E:\Projects\VHDL\New_Phase\toplevel.vhd" line 296: Output port <MAX5190_CHIRP_ENABLE_TRIGGER> of the instance <contr> is unconnected or connected to loadless signal.

INFO:Xst:3210 - "E:\Projects\VHDL\New_Phase\toplevel.vhd" line 365: Output port <DATA_OUT> of the instance <gen[1].memcont> is unconnected or connected to loadless signal.

INFO:Xst:3210 - "E:\Projects\VHDL\New_Phase\toplevel.vhd" line 365: Output port <DINA> of the instance <gen[1].memcont> is unconnected or connected to loadless signal.

INFO:Xst:3210 - "E:\Projects\VHDL\New_Phase\toplevel.vhd" line 365: Output port <ADDRA> of the instance <gen[1].memcont> is unconnected or connected to loadless signal.

INFO:Xst:3210 - "E:\Projects\VHDL\New_Phase\toplevel.vhd" line 365: Output port <WEA> of the instance <gen[1].memcont> is unconnected or connected to loadless signal.

INFO:Xst:3210 - "E:\Projects\VHDL\New_Phase\toplevel.vhd" line 365: Output port <RSTA> of the instance <gen[1].memcont> is unconnected or connected to loadless signal.

INFO:Xst:3210 - "E:\Projects\VHDL\New_Phase\toplevel.vhd" line 391: Output port <DATA_ADDR> of the instance <gen[1].max> is unconnected or connected to loadless signal.

INFO:Xst:3210 - "E:\Projects\VHDL\New_Phase\toplevel.vhd" line 391: Output port <DAC_DATA> of the instance <gen[1].max> is unconnected or connected to loadless signal.

INFO:Xst:3210 - "E:\Projects\VHDL\New_Phase\toplevel.vhd" line 414: Output port <douta> of the instance <gen[1].mem> is unconnected or connected to loadless signal.
```

These errors repeat themselves for every generated object.
The input ports are given default values because the compiler kept asking for it with errors (don't know why either though).

If anyone could help me that would be fantastic!!

Comment: This is not a [MInimal Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The first three error signals are not found in your code snippets. DATA_OUT interconnects memory_cont and max. An elaboration asking for defaults on input ports indicates they are unconnected. Your code snippets aren't sufficient to answer your question. Does your design simulate?

Comment: @user1155120 the first three errors weren't supposed to be in this topic. Those three I expected. As you can see, the ports are connected, so it shouldn't ask for it. But as you can read below I've gone for the long and not modular way to solve the problem. Thanks for your interest anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The signal that are connected to the instantiated modules are simply not used, thus for example the message "Output port <DATA_OUT> of the instance <gen[1].memcont> is unconnected or connected to loadless signal".

So take a look at modules where the components are instantiated, or a module above, connect the output from the instantiated modules, since the output is probably there to be used ;-)

Comment: But the `DATA_OUT` output from the `memory_controll` is connected to the `DIN` input from the `MAX5190` via the `DATA_OUT` signal.

But I think it has something to do with the generate loop and/or the `TYPE DATA_ARRAY     is array (POSITIVE) of STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0);`.

Comment: The connection itself does not ensure that there is actually a load, so check if the `DIN` of `MAX5190` actually uses output.

Comment: It does, I've simulated all the components separately in Isim and the three components mentioned above together, but now with the array of std_logic_vectors it says it isn't connected. Could that be the problem? If yes, any idea how to solve it?

Comment: The array itself is unlikely to be the problem, but only the symptom.  If signals are not output from the FPGA, then the logic driving those signals will be optimized away, and that may lead to the problem you see.  Note that the design can still simulate, since such optimization is made in synthesis only, but not in simulation.

Comment: You've put me in the right direction. I've started floorplan and found out it doesn't recognize the 'CHANNELS : OUT VECTOR_ARRAY(8);' as output. So I guess it's not possible to use a array of std_logic_vectors as output signal?
I've created new ports and changed the 'CHANNELS' to a signal. Now floorplan finds the output ports, I've assigned all ports to a pin and synthesized the whole again. Still got the same messages.

Comment: I also got a warning that the digital clock multiplier I created with IPCORE remains a black box, could this be the problem if the compiler thinks the modules doesnt have a clock?

Comment: I've removed the arrays and the generate loop and these warnings are gone now, so it had to do something with the arrays. It also tied up stuff in the schematics it shouldn't do.
So a little more code now, but it works.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your are welcome.  Remember to accept the answer by clicking the check mark, as described in [accepted-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer), so others won't spend time reading and answering this fixed problem.